# Hilbert’s third problem and what a polyhedron is

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, polyhedra, definitions

What is the definition of a polyhedron used by Hilbert’s third problem?

Comment: This MO website is for questions of math research. I'm not seeing a research angle to this question.

Comment: If the question is about Hilbert's original problem statement, as it seems, it would have been better suited to [History of Science and Mathematics](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 4):

The question itself is interesting, because in historical contexts (sometimes even modern ones) it is not always clear what a polyhedron means. To anyone who thinks this is evident from the outset, I would encourage having a look at Lakatos's entertaining 1976 book [*Proofs and Refutations*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proofs_and_Refutations). Before reading the book, I thought I had a pretty clear idea of the possible problem cases where Euler's formula $V-E+F=2$ fails, but I had myself surprised.

In Hilbert's case we should look into the original text. His question starts with tetrahedra. To wit, [original text](https://www.deutschestextarchiv.de/book/view/hilbert_mathematische_1900?p=23), as printed in *Göttinger Nachrichten*, 1900, pp. 253–297,

> Ein solcher wäre erbracht, sobald es gelingt, zwei Tetraeder mit
> gleicher Grundfläche und von gleicher Höhe anzugeben, die sich auf
> keine Weise in congruente Tetraeder zerlegen lassen und die sich auch
> durch Hinzufügung congruenter Tetraeder nicht zu solchen Polyedern
> ergänzen lassen, für die ihrerseits eine Zerlegung in congruente
> Tetraeder möglich ist.

and [English translation](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Mathematical_Problems) by [Mary Newson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mary_Frances_Winston_Newson),

> This would be obtained, as soon as we succeeded in specifying two
> tetrahedra of equal bases and equal altitudes which can in no way be
> split up into congruent tetrahedra, and which cannot be combined with
> congruent tetrahedra to form two polyhedra which themselves could be
> split up into congruent tetrahedra.

There are some points worth pondering here — which I did not notice at first!

1. Hilbert talks not only about splitting the tetrahedra, but also
   about combining them *into polyhedra*. From the context, it seems a
   polyhedron here is anything you can obtain by such combination; for
   example, *holes are allowed* and *convexity is not required*.
2. The wording with "splitting" and "combining" seems to imply that the
   interiors of pieces are disjoint. We are splitting and combining
   *solids*. (No star polyhedra!)
3. Although the word "finite" is conspicuously absent, it seems obviously
   implied that both splitting and combining is with
   *finite* number of pieces, because the whole point is to avoid
   "exhaustion".